# problem in embedding flash file in html

Tags: php, html, flash

Can any body check this code please..

```
    <?php

$hl_1  = $_POST['hl_1'];
$bc_1  = $_POST['bc_1'];

$hl_2  = $_POST['hl_2'];
$bc_2  = $_POST['bc_2'];

$hl_3  = $_POST['hl_3'];
$bc_3  = $_POST['bc_3'];

$hl_4  = $_POST['hl_4'];
$bc_4  = $_POST['bc_4'];

$cta  = $_POST['cta'];
$cta_select  = $_POST['cta_select'];

$share_on  = $_POST['share_on'];
$share_url  = $_POST['share_url'];

$install_url  = $_POST['install_url'];
$aff_link  = $_POST['aff_link'];

$color_select = $_POST['color_select'];
$pattern_select = $_POST['pattern_select'];
$texture_select = $_POST['texture_select'];

$bann_size  = $_POST['bann_size'];

$ov_1  = $_POST['ov_1'];
$ov_2  = $_POST['ov_2'];
$ov_3  = $_POST['ov_3'];
$ov_4  = $_POST['ov_4'];
$ov_5  = $_POST['ov_5'];
$ov_6  = $_POST['ov_6'];
$ov_7  = $_POST['ov_7'];
$ov_8  = $_POST['ov_8'];
$ov_9  = $_POST['ov_9'];
$ov_10  = $_POST['ov_10'];
$ov_11  = $_POST['ov_11'];
$ov_12  = $_POST['ov_12'];
$ov_13  = $_POST['ov_13'];
$ov_14  = $_POST['ov_14'];
$ov_15  = $_POST['ov_15'];
$ov_16  = $_POST['ov_16'];
$ov_17  = $_POST['ov_17'];
$ov_18  = $_POST['ov_18'];
$ov_19  = $_POST['ov_19'];

$ani_1  = $_POST['ani_1'];
$ani_2  = $_POST['ani_2'];
$ani_3  = $_POST['ani_3'];
$ani_4  = $_POST['ani_4'];
$ani_5  = $_POST['ani_5'];
$ani_6  = $_POST['ani_6'];
$ani_7  = $_POST['ani_7'];
$ani_8  = $_POST['ani_8'];
$ani_9  = $_POST['ani_9'];





$redirect_linker  = $_POST['redirect_linker'];

$aff_redirect = 'y';
$CTA_txt  = $_POST['CTA_txt'];

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CreateBannersOnline.com Creating Banners Online Just got Better!</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />




</head>

<body>

<div id="mainWrapper">

    <div id="mainHeaderArea">

    </div>

    <div id="mainContentArea">

    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="" valign="top" >

        <div id="App-Area">

            <div id="IntroArea">
            <p style="intro"><strong>Let's Get Started &amp; Create A Quick Banner!</strong></p>
            <p>In only 4 steps you will have your own Banner Advertisement that you can use to give your affiliates so they can start promoting your product, service, and offers!</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            </div>


        <div id="Preview">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Banner Preview - 250x250</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>


      <div align="center">  <embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/250x250.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="250" height="250" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

        </div>

        </div>
        <br /><br />
                  <form action="embed.php" method="post">
            <div id="step-area">

<label class="pencil">Copy & Paste This: <strong>your banner code</strong></label>
    (250x250)           
    <textarea name="embed"><embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/250x250.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="250" height="250" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" /></textarea>


            </div>

        </form>

             <div id="Preview">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Banner Preview - 468x60</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>


      <div align="center">  <embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/468x60.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="468" height="60" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

        </div>

        </div>
        <br /><br />
                  <form action="embed.php" method="post">
            <div id="step-area">

<label class="pencil">Copy & Paste This: <strong>your banner code</strong></label>
    (250x250)           
    <textarea name="embed"><embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/468x60.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="468" height="60" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" /></textarea>


            </div>

        </form>

             <div id="Preview">

        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Banner Preview - 160x600</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>


      <div align="center">  <embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/160x600.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="160" height="600" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />

        </div>

        </div>
        <br /><br />
                  <form action="embed.php" method="post">
            <div id="step-area">

<label class="pencil">Copy & Paste This: <strong>your banner code</strong></label>
    (250x250)           
    <textarea name="embed"><embed src="http://createbannersonline.com/banners/160x600.swf?copy1=<?= urlencode($hl_1) ?>&body1=<?= urlencode($bc_1) ?>&copy2=<?= urlencode($hl_2) ?>&body2=<?= urlencode($bc_2) ?>&copy3=<?= urlencode($hl_3) ?>&body3=<?= urlencode($bc_3) ?>&copy4=<?= urlencode($hl_4) ?>&body4=<?= urlencode($bc_4) ?>&ctacopy=<?= urlencode($cta) ?>&sharevar=<?= $share_on ?>&shareurl=<?= urlencode($share_url) ?>&afflink=<?= urlencode($aff_link) ?>&colorp=<?= $color_select ?>&patternp=<?= $pattern_select ?>&texturep=<?= $texture_select ?>&ctap=<?= $cta_select ?>&ovp1=<?= $ov_1 ?>&ovp2=<?= $ov_2 ?>&ovp3=<?= $ov_3 ?>&ovp4=<?= $ov_4 ?>&ovp5=<?= $ov_5 ?>&ovp6=<?= $ov_6 ?>&ovp7=<?= $ov_7 ?>&ovp8=<?= $ov_8 ?>&ovp9=<?= $ov_9 ?>&ovp10=<?= $ov_10 ?>&ovp11=<?= $ov_11 ?>&ovp12=<?= $ov_12 ?>&ovp13=<?= $ov_13 ?>&ovp14=<?= $ov_14 ?>&ovp15=<?= $ov_15 ?>&ovp16=<?= $ov_16 ?>&ovp17=<?= $ov_17 ?>&ovp18=<?= $ov_18 ?>&ovp19=<?= $ov_19 ?>&anip1=<?= $ani_1 ?>&anip2=<?= $ani_2 ?>&anip3=<?= $ani_3 ?>&anip4=<?= $ani_4 ?>&anip5=<?= $ani_5 ?>&anip6=<?= $ani_6 ?>&anip7=<?= $ani_7 ?>&anip8=<?= $ani_8 ?>&anip9=<?= $ani_9 ?>" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFF" width="160" height="600" name="250x250" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" /></textarea>


            </div>

        </form>

        </div>

        </td>
        <td width="245" valign="top" >

        <div id="Left-Area">

        <p align="center">* Here you will find great resources that you can use to create a better banners to promote other offers!*</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>


        <img src="images/create-tools.jpg"  />

       <a href="index.php"><img src="images/create-banner.jpg" border="0"  /></a>
       <a href="index-video.php"><img src="images/create-viral-video.jpg" border="0"  /></a>

        <br />


        <img src="images/right-top-part.gif"  />
            <a href="Bonus/AdvertisingHandbook.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/bonus-pdf.jpg" border="0"  /></a>
       <a href="Bonus/Awesome%20Advertising%20Tips.mp3" target="_blank" ><img src="images/bonus-mp3.jpg" border="0"  /></a>


        </div>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    </div>

    <div id="FooterArea">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have problem in previewing last banner.

here is the [Sample Output](http://www.createbannersonline.com/embed-250.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last file (the SWF) doesn't exist. Make sure the file exists along with the other ones and that there aren't any typos.